# php send variable to other php file?

Tags: php, jquery, http, post, get

I understand this question has likely been asked before, but nothing is simple, straightforward, and to the point for a beginning php or ajax/jquery programmer. The problem is identifying which link has been clicked on one html/php page, and then pulling up a different php page accordingly. In other words, what is the best way to send a string from one php file to another, without using forms?

Comment: ofcourse `ajax` and jquery ajax does it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is pretty straightforward:

page_a.php:

```
<a href="page_b.php?bar=foo">link</a>
```

page_b.php

```
Hey, I got "<?php echo $_GET['bar']; ?>" from page a !
```

Which would display:

> Hey, I got "foo" from page a !

Note that you should test if the variable has been set:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['bar'])) {
    echo $_GET['bar'];
}
?>
```

If you want to pass more variables, add a `&` and append them to the url:

```
page_a.php?var1=text1&var2=text2&var3=...
```

And you retrieve them the exact same way (still, you want to check everything before, I didn't do it for readability):

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET['var1']; // = text1
$var2 = $_GET['var2']; // = text2
$var3 = $_GET['var3']; // = ...
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variables can store information that can used all over the website.

Although as I read this:

> The problem is identifying which link has been clicked on one html/php page, and then pulling up a different php page accordingly

This sounds like a hyperlink?

Comment: The php file I link to pulls in a different php file according to the link clicked in the original file (so three files total). All hyperlinks in the original file are pointing to the intermediary php file.

Comment: Yeah you can use GET or Session Variables, either of them will keep track of whatever value you wish to pass to the middle man.